# Java Putting a Vector into another Vector

Tags: java, vector, copy, clone

When I use these lines:

```
vector.set(i, copyedVector.clone());

vector holds Vector<String>

copyVector holds strings
```

It gives me an error when I use clone. But when I remove clone, it works fine. How do I make a copy of a vector into the other vector?

Comment: From what you're saying, each element in your `Vector` holds a `Vector` of `String`s?  If you're `Vector` is actually just a list of `String`s you should use [`Vector.addAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which will copy each element from source `Vector` into this one...?

Comment: FYI, you probably would be better off using a different collection type rather than `Vector` (e.g. `ArrayList`). See [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, it is not clear if you "vector" variable is a Vector of Vectors (`Vector<Vector<String>>`) or simply a Vector of Strings (`Vector<String>`). Please see the following code snippet.

```
Vector<String> destVector = new Vector<String>();
Vector<String> sourceVector = new Vector<String>();
sourceVector.add("A");
sourceVector.add("B");
sourceVector.add("C");
destVector.addAll(0,sourceVector);

// If your target vector is a vector of vectors (of strings)
Vector<Vector<String>> destVector2 = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
destVector2.set(0,(Vector<String>)sourceVector.clone());
```

Also, please note that the `clone` method returns an `Object`. So you will have to explicitly cast to your desired data type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking but if you want to copy all the element you can use the addAll method and pass the vector to copy elements from into it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
vector.set(i, new Vector().addAll(copyedVector));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add data to vectors by yourself.

```
Vector<T> vector1 = new Vector<T>();
Vector<T> vector2 = new Vector<T>();

vector1.addAll(vector2);
```